# Why does it need two clicks in D3.js for my click event to fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I have a button inside a **svg** `foreignObject` and I have appended a *click event* to the foreignObject via D3. The click event fires, but only the second time I click the foreignObject. What happens on first click is that the button gets *active* (blue border). So once it is active it only takes one click to fire the event.

I suppose the problem is that the group to which the button is appended somehow is in the background, but I am not sure because the issue occurs with only one `<g>` added, too.

I have also tried binding the click event directly to the button, too. But the behaviour did not change.

Here is my code (this is close to as minimal as I needed to make it work): [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km04o82t/)

How can I change it, so that the click event fires every time (at first click) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to not use raise()

Instead of

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);<--- seems like raise eating up the event.
}
```

use this

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
}
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfabg638/)

Comment: @frankenapps The reason for removing `raise()` from the `dragstarted` is that `raise` re-appends the element, and that prevents the browser from dispatching the click event. You can simply move `raise` to the `dragged` function.